# Torque of a wire tensioner dancing arm

Tags: classical-mechanics, torque, rotation

I'm creating a wire tensioning sub-system for a coil winder, and I've decided to use a dancing arm to measure the tension in the wire as it is pulled off a supply reel, like so:

[image]

As the tension in the wire decreases (T), the lever arm with the load (L)
moves downward, and as the tension in the wire increases, the dancing arm moves up. The position of the dancing arm sends a signal to a controller which controls a brake attached to the reel.

The idea here is to keep the tension in the wire constant by increasing and decreasing the torque supplied by the brake in response to changes in the tension in the wire from the winding process.

What I'm having trouble with is finding an equation connecting the tension experienced by both parts of the wire near the stationary rollers(T1) to the force experienced by the dancing arm. I need to know if there is a tension in the wire how much force (And thus torque) the dancing arm experiences.

With this I can determine how long to make the lever arm, in order to set how much torque is supplied to the reel per each degree of movement in the dancing arm.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please show some effort to tackle this problem yourself. What have you come up with so far, and why don't you think it is correct?

Comment: I believe the lever arm acts like a moving pulley, with the tension in each part of the wire wrapping around it being half the load(T = F/2) when the system is not winding,  hence the force acting on the lever being -F or -2T (Downwards). However when the system is winding the tension in the wire will become larger than the load and the arm will move up, and I'm assuming that the force acting on the arm will be 2T(Upwards), with T now being the load plus the force supplied by the winder system. I'm not sure if this is right, as one end of the pulley system is not fixed (The Reel).